# Alternative to Field Collection

Tags: entities

Does anyone know an alternative to the module "field collection" ?

While the concept of field collection is very good, I'm having trouble with the collaboration of other modules, like e.g. features or search api. So I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: Field collection really is the top drupal module for solving problems if it's class. I have found it's support across different modules is great. It works with features, and you simply have to make sure your display preferences are setup  correctly for it to work with search.

Comment: Sam, I'm not sure what you mean by "correct display preferences". Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 11):

See the [Multifield](https://drupal.org/project/multifield) module.

> This project seeks to provide a true compound field solution for
>   Drupal 7. As much as I love Field collection, it still has to save
>   actual entities, and can cause performance problems due to having to
>   load all the referenced field collection entities on node, or parent
>   entity load.

I am not sure of its compatibility with Features or Search API though.

Comment: That module is currently "unstable" so use with caution on a dev site, but definitely don't use on a live site without heavy testing

Comment: Unfortunately Feeds does not support multifield import out of the box so this may not be a viable option if you are looking to import data in to this field

Comment: The "Related Links" section on the multifield module page is helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Try the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module, it integrates with Search API and [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features).

Comment: Yes, paragraphs is best alternative to Field_collection.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider creating a new content type to represent the collection and then using Inline Entity Form to allow creation of the 'collection' inside of the content type referencing it. See: [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).

Comment: But does this integrate with Search? I want to get the "whole Page" as a search result and not only the "inline Content Type" ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'whole page' as a search result. Can you clarify?

Comment: For example: I'm using the Content Typ "B" within my Content Type "A" as an Inline Entity Form just as you described (this Content Type B contains the string "test"). When I now search for the string "test" - what will I get as the search result? From my point of view it must be the node of the Content Type B. But want I want is the node of the Content Type A (that contains the CT B).

Comment: This is essentially what field collections accomplish, but in a far more streamlined manner.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation scar. Looking at Search API there is an issue queue explanation that essentially says: if the contrib module is correctly built then yes. (https://drupal.org/node/1118282) Since IEF supports Entity Reference module fields that would be the module to check. The issue queue there does seem to indicate that it *should* work with this issue here: https://drupal.org/node/1651606.

Comment: The above link was broken by a typo (a period). For your convenience:
[Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)