# Field Collection vs. Paragraphs

Tags: 7, database, performance, entities

I used [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) in my previous sites and I faced some performance issue, So this time I am looking a alternative for [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection). I find a answer [Alternative to Field Collection](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/alternative-to-field-collection).

but I can't find much on how different or similar these solutions specially [**[Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) and [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)**].

Maybe someone can help to explain? So that I can make a good decision.

Comment: do you got some advance with your research?

Comment: No, Not much still i am looking for some better alternative.

Comment: if you want you can read this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/121604/28275

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In many respects the Paragraphs module appears to be a fork of Field Collection. Functionally, the difference between the modules lies in how their respective field widgets operate. The Field Collection widget allows users to embed multiple instances of a single field collection bundle in a node, while Paragraphs allows users to select a different bundle for each instance they embed using the Paragraphs widget. Both of these methods are extremely valuable and I now find myself combining field collections and paragraphs on the same node.

Read more in the issue about "[Merge with Paragraphs module?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2287763)".